# Redirect URL with query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, query-string

i am currently tasked with permanently redirecting multiple URLs for a client. I am using the "Redirect 301" command for URLs without query strings, which works fine.

Now i need to permanently redirect multiple selective URLs including query strings. The problem is, that i am not allowed to rewrite the query strings to nice looking URLs, so i need to find a way to redirect the old URLs with query strings to new URLs with query strings (oh boy).

Example(s):

```
Old: /loremipsum/dolorsit/?lang=en
New: /consetetur/sadipscing/?lang=en

Old: /dolorsit/?lang=en
New: /sadipscing/?lang=en

Old: /loremipsum/dolorsit/?lang=it
New: /consetetur/sadipscing/?lang=it

Old: /dolorsit/?lang=it
New: /sadipscing/?lang=it
```

Since the URLs are always different and selective, i can't use some sort off mass redirect.
What i would need to do is redirect every single URL to the new URL by hand, both using query strings.

I was using:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en$
RewriteRule ^loremipsum/dolorsit/$ http://domain.com/consetetur/sadipscing/?lang=en [R=301,L]
```

It only works when not appending the query string, which is weird.

Help would be much appreciated, i am really going nuts on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en$
RewriteRule ^loremipsum/?$ /dolorsit/ [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=it$
RewriteRule ^loremipsum/?$ /consetetur/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Query String is by default appended to target URL so `?lang=en` will be appended to new URL on its own.

Comment: Thanks mate, you made my day! Just one more thing: Do i need to add the RewriteCond to every new RewriteRule (say i need to redirect 10 URLs with the same query string) or only for a new/different query string?

Comment: You can just comment out `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en$` and rule will still work.

Comment: Damn, i just realized that i've got different URLs i need to redirect to, for example: "/loremipsum/?lang=en" needs to redirect to "/dolorsit/?lang=en" and "/loremipsum/?lang=it" needs to redirect to "/consetetur/?lang=it". So the same base URL needs to redirect to different URLs depending on the language query string.

Comment: Hmm ok in that you need to use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en$` and `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=it$` for each `RewriteRule`

Comment: I am now using two RewriteRules, each with it's own RewriteCond. The first RewriteRule with cond ^lang=en$ works fine, the second RewriteRule with cond ^lang=it$ redirects to the URL of the first RewriteRule.

Comment: see updated rule. You can have rules like this for each query string.

Comment: "loremipsum/?lang=it" still redirects to "/dolorsit/?lang=it" and not to "/consetetur/?lang=it" as it should. Using your updated rule.

Comment: Use a new browser to test and make sure you have just these 2 rules as shown here. (no other conflicting rule)

Comment: Still no luck. The old italian URL still redirects to the new english URL and not the new italian URL.

Comment: This rule is 100% correct that is all I can tell you.